# Get parameter + replace with space when processing in action class

Tags: java, encryption, struts2

I encrypt a text "good-bye, friend" using `BasicTextEncryptor`. So the encrypt value looks like below,

```
3qe80L1ap+cR2zRU9csFwOffw5NtWTueLRYgSXyjctI=
```

Then I email a URL to the user where the above parameter as a token.

Then the user copies the below URL and presses enter,

```
http://localhost:8080/token=3qe80L1ap+cR2zRU9csFwOffw5NtWTueLRYgSXyjctI=
```

But when I access the parameter in Struts 2 application through the action method it gives me the encrypt parameter as below,

```
3qe80L1ap cR2zRU9csFwOffw5NtWTueLRYgSXyjctI=
```

The `+` is replaced by `" "`. So when I decrypt it, it gives me `EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException`.

Does struts decode the `+` to `" "` assuming browser `+` is a encode character? In that case it ok before I proceed with decrypt, I replace the space with `+` ?

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better way would be to  "URL encode" the string before appending it to actual URL.

```
URLEncoder.encode("3qe80L1ap+cR2zRU9csFwOffw5NtWTueLRYgSXyjctI=", "ISO-8859-1");
```

This would make sure the token is correctly decoded.

To, answer your question, struts does not have any role in decoding the URL parameter. Its the **core functionality of the application server to decode the URL parameter**. So every HTTP parameter is subjected to decoding before reaching the application code.

Whatever is decoded by the server is available by to the application (i.e. Struts in your case. )

Now to explain why the `+` is not reaching your struts.

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode("3qe80L1ap+cR2zRU9csFwOffw5NtWTueLRYgSXyjctI="));
```

it returns `3qe80L1ap cR2zRU9csFwOffw5NtWTueLRYgSXyjctI=`

which means that `+` is not getting URL Decoded.

So, reiterating,  every HTTP parameter (querystring or form POST) is subjected to decoding before reaching the application code.

When you URL encode your string, `+` is encoded as `%2B` and your struts application will receive the correct decoded string.

Comment: Note that you should honor the recommendation in the javadoc for URLEncoder.encode() – always use UTF-8 as the character encoding.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to not put the base64 encoded string there, but encode it using the UrlEncoder, like the following:

```
URLEncoder.encode("3qe80L1ap+cR2zRU9csFwOffw5NtWTueLRYgSXyjctI=", "UTF-8")
```

That way you can put it in the link.

Answer (score 0):

> URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a `+` sign.

Thus the server decodes normally `+` sign to the space. See [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) docs or read [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10786042/573032).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a so called *URL safe* variant of Base64. The most common variant, described in RFC 4648, uses `-` and `_` instead of `+` and `/` respectively, and omits padding characters (`=`).

Most implementations of Base64 support this URL safe variant too, though if yours doesn't, it's easy enough to do manually.